# Creating relationship between models when in separate files FLASK, SQLalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

How can I properly establish a foreign key relationship between these two models when they are currently in separate folders?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, DateTime, ForeignKey
from testserver.database import Base
from datetime import datetime


class Service(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'services'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    date_created = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    provider_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('provider.id'))
```

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from testserver.database import Base
from datetime import datetime
from testserver.database import db_session


class Provider(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'providers'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    date_created = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    services = relationship(
        'Service', cascade='all, delete-orphan', backref='provided_by')
```

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr


class Base(object):
    __abstract__ = True

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
```

the code above currently throws an err:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'services.provider_id' could not find table 'provider' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

any recommendations or solutions would be greatly apprecieted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have a typo here:

```py
provider_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('provider.id'))
```

In relationship you provided lowercased model name, instead of table name. If you replace `provider` with `providers` (because it is a name of your table) it should fix your problem

```py
provider_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('providers.id'))
```